# Renaming files using directory path

Tags: bash, scripts

I could use some help with a shell script to rename files using portions of the directory tree and existing file name.

**Background:** The file naming convention is from an Amcrest security camera that cannot be modified. The camera creates a new folder for every minute and every hour of the day.

The jpeg files are created using the seconds past the minute.

Current naming structure:

```
AMC0103W_93Sxxx/2017-02-07/001/jpg.14/02/29[M][0@0][0].jpg
```

where 14 is the hour, 02 is the minute, and 29 is the seconds.

Here's the format that I'd like to have:

```
AMC0103W_93Sxxx/2017-02-07/140229.jpg
```

My goal is to set a `crontab` job that runs hourly to rename these into a new directory then deletes the old directory and files.

Comment: In your case specifically (assuming the backslashes are a mistake(!)) you could use something like `find AMC0103W_93Sxxx -type f | rename -n 's|(.*/)[^/]+/jpg/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^[]*)\[.*|$1$2$3$4.jpg|'` (remove `-n` and run it again if the output looks correct)

Comment: Who the hell uses backslashes in file names?

Comment: The backslashes were definitely wrong, I fixed that.  A longtime windows user, got used to backslash.

Comment: IoT security is terrible: expect your camera images to be published on the internet: https://www.secplicity.org/2017/01/18/responsible-disclosure-amcrest-view-web-portal/

Comment: https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/amcrest-prohd-camera-serious-security-issue/ -- make sure you update your camera's firmware

Answer (score 1):

Zanna your solution worked perfectly, thank you.
As for the security issues with these cameras, I agree with you & the reason I'm storing these on my own internal FTP server vs using these iffy cloud hosting services for cameras.

Your script:

```
find AMC0103W_93Sxxx -type f | rename -n 's|(.*/)[^/]+/jpg/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^[]*)\[.*|$1$2$3$4.jpg|'
```

The output:

```
rename(AMC0103W_93Sxxx/2017-02-11/001/jpg/07/02/27[M][0@0][0].jpg, AMC0103W_93Sxxx/2017-02-11/070227.jpg)
```